# How can I redirect to the object in an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have action `index`:

```
def index
  if params['type'] == 'random'
    @objects = Object.order("RANDOM()").limit(1)
  else
    @objects = Object.all.limit(1)
  end
end
```

and `create` action:

```
def create
  object = Object.find(params[:object_id])
  comment = object.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:body))

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html 
    format.js #ajax
  end

  if comment.save
    redirect_to root_path(params[:object_id]) #doesn't work
  else
    flash[:error] = comment.errors.full_messages[0]
    redirect_to root_path(params[:object_id]) #doesn't work
  end
end
```

I can comment an object in my `index` page. When I put a comment, I want to redirect to the object that was commented.

With my code, the page is reloaded, but the next object is displayed, and I cannot see the comment. How can I redirect to the same object?

My `root_path`

```
<span class="random-icon"><%= link_to icon('random'), "http://localhost:3000/?type=random" %></span>

<div class="inner-container">
    <% @objects.each do |object| %>
      <h1 class="title"><%= object.title %></h1>
      <p class="obj"><%= object.body %></p>
      <h3 class="comments-title">Comments:</h3>
      <div id="comments">  
        <% object.comments.each do |comment| %>
          <div class="comments"> <%= comment.body %> 
            <span class="time-to-now"><%= distance_of_time_in_words_to_now(comment.created_at) %> ago</span>
          </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>

        <div id="error"><%= flash[:error] %></div>
        <%= form_for([object, object.comments.build], remote: true) do |f| %>
          <%= f.text_area :body, class: "text-area" %> 
          <p class="char-limit">255 characters limit</p>
          <%= f.submit "Comment", class: 'button' %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: What is in `root_path`? Can you show the code?

Comment: I don't think that the `root_path` receives any parameters here. Do you have any path like `show_object`, which receives the `object_id` as a parameter?

Comment: No, I need to do on index page only, I cant to use show page.

Comment: You shouldn't limit the results to 1 on the index page.

Answer (score 1):

If `params['type']` is true, `Object.order("RANDOM()").limit(1)` will always br reevaluated and usually return a new object. To ensure you return to the same object, you might want to store it in session and then check first in your index if there is a liked comment in your sessions, if so, `@objects = Object.find(session[:comment_object_id])`

```
def index
  if session[:comment_object_id]
    @objects = Object.find(session[:comment_object_id])
    session.delete(:comment_object_id) # delete the session after use
  elsif params['type'] == 'random'
    @objects = Object.order("RANDOM()").limit(1)
  else
    @objects = Object.all.limit(1)
  end
end


def create
   object = Object.find(params[:id])
   comment = object.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:body))

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html 
    format.js #ajax
  end

  if comment.save
    session[:comment_object_id] = :object_id # set the session here
    redirect_to root_path # should work now
  else
    flash[:error] = comment.errors.full_messages[0]
    redirect_to root_path #should work now
  end
end
```

Comment: return this error: Couldn't find Object with 'id'=object_id in this line: @objects = Object.find(session[:comment_object_id])

Comment: Are you sure you used `:comment_object_id` to set the session in your create action?

Comment: I guess I know where the problem is, I'd edit the create action. You need just `id` and not `object_id`.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy, and you're very close.

Inside your `create` method, you've got the `object` you want to redirect to. So just use it directly inside the `if comment.save` like:

`redirect_to object_path(object)`

You can get a list of all these `path` "helpers" via the command:

`rake routes`

And in that listing, you should see, by the way, that `root_path` does not accept any arguments ... for future reference.